# Semantic attributes and prefixes on properties

Tags: dxa

In [this question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15473/how-to-map-model-for-a-schema-which-has-multiple-value-component-link-field-wit), ([How to map Model for a Schema, which has multiple value Component link field with multiple allowed Schemas?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15473/how-to-map-model-for-a-schema-which-has-multiple-value-component-link-field-wit)) Stan has given a step-by-step answer for the solution and Rick replied to his answer with several tips.  One of the tips says:

> Note that if you use a Prefix in your SemanticEntity annotation (which
>   I would not recommend), you must also use that in your
>   SemanticProperty annotation. For example:
>   [SemanticProperty("s:componentLink")]

Why would a prefix annotation not be recommended?

Answer (score 3):

That is purely for simplicity reasons (KISS principle). You need to use a prefix if:

- You want to publicly expose the semantics (`Public=true`) in your HTML , e.g. for SEO purposes. In this case you should ensure you use a well-known, public vocabulary (e.g. schema.org).
- You want to map a View Model type to multiple CM Schemas (by giving it multiple `SemanticEntity` annotations). In this case you should use a different prefix for each semantic type.

If you don't have these requirements, you can do without prefix. You can still use a prefix if you like complexity, though. :-)