# DXA 1.7 Entity Model for multiple possible Linked Components

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

While we are migrating our existing webapp to DXA 1.7 Java, we encountered following problem: We have multiple Schemas where more than one Schema is available as Component Link. See screenshot:

[image]

So the question is: How would the entity model in Java look like for this issue? Currently we only got it working for only one Schema (in this example: Content Teaser) at a time but not for multiple Schemas.

EDIT: All Linked Schemas have completely different XML fields and do have nothing in common.

Comment: You may want to try this: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15473/how-to-map-model-for-a-schema-which-has-multiple-value-component-link-field-wit

Comment: Looks like a duplicate indeed, if that is not the case, please **edit** the question and clarify why this is different than https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15473/how-to-map-model-for-a-schema-which-has-multiple-value-component-link-field-wit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Diego Rodríguez](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/2011/diego-rodr%C3%ADguez) for the answer. We ran a first test with our DXA Java implementation together with multiple `@SemanticProperty` in our Entity Model and we were able to successfully get results in the Front-End.

Entity model looks kind of like this:
[image]

There are some new challenges now like a correct Partial approach for better reusability but we are good to continue so far. Thank you!

Comment: Consider using the approach with a common base class (described by Stanislav in the same StackExchange topic) instead. It results in much cleaner View Model and View code.